How to use Copilot in VS2022 with bitbucket as source repo
Is there a way of using GitHub copilot in VS 2022 enterprise edition [v17.7] with bitbucket private repository.
We added copilot extension for VS 2022 and an error popup , asking us to enter github details.
We are using bitbucket as our source code repository.
